# Is there any way to still use APIs lower than 26 as target SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Specifically I wanted to use API 24 for my project. So this is what I set in `build.gradle`.

[image: Google Play requires that apps target API level 26 or higher]

Now as you can see, Android Studio is forcing the use of API level 26 or higher. I only have API 24 and below installed. I don't want to download more APIs because what I am trying to develop is an in-house app and won't be needed to be uploaded in Google Play.

So is there a procedure so that Android Studio can accept this settings and override the requirement?

Comment: i suggest you to lower buildToolsVersion to suffice the targetSdkVersion, otherwise you need to update your targetSdkVersion as well with the compiledSdkVersion to specified lint :)

Comment: using lower version target is not recommended and it is not possible with Android studio in general but you can disable that error message and proceed with coding, or else use any other tools to develop your app other than android studio

Comment: Lower the Gradle plugin version. It will work

Comment: You can build and run the app but it can't be published on Google play.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled this lint check during my build by adding the following as a **child of my "android" node** in my Kotlin Gradle build file, build.gradle.kts:

```
lint {
    disable.add("ExpiredTargetSdkVersion")
}
```

If instead you have a Groovy build.gradle file, you might have to do it this way instead:

```
lint {
    disable += ['ExpiredTargetSdkVersion']
}
```

I came up with this via the following steps:

1. finding Android Gradle plugin API reference:
   https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api
2. guess the 8.0.2 version sounded familiar to what I was using:
   https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.0/classes
3. find "**Lint**" under "L":
   https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/Lint
4. this describes the "**disable**" option. But using += as shown on this page gave me "Overload resolution ambiguity" errors (after I changed the apostrophes around the string to quotation marks).
5. eventually I hovered on the "disable" option in Android Studio and it showed me the type was **MutableSet<String>**.
6. I googled "**Kotlin add item to MutableSet**" and the top result was:
   https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-set/
7. That page shows the **.add** method I used successfully to add my desired value and make the linter ignore this.

Answer (score -1):

From official documentation, https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

> Why target newer SDKs? Every new Android version introduces changes
> that bring significant security and performance improvements as well
> as enhance the user experience of Android overall. Some of these
> changes only apply to apps that explicitly declare support through
> their targetSdkVersion manifest attribute (also known as the target
> API level).
>
> Configuring your app to target a recent API level ensures that users
> can benefit from these improvements, while still allowing it to run on
> older Android versions. Targeting a recent API level also allows your
> app to take advantage of the platform's latest features to delight
> your users. Furthermore, as of Android 10 (API level 29), users see a
> warning when starting an app for the first time if the app targets
> Android 5.1 (API level 22) or lower.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question `So is there a procedure so that Android Studio can accept this settings and override the requirement?`

Comment: Im using Android studio. 4.0, Im not experiencing this issue